# Cast a hexadecimal string to an array of bigint in hive

Tags: hive

I have a column that contains a length 16 hexademical string. I would like to convert it to a bigint. Is there any way to accomplish that? The usual approach returns null since the input string could represent a number > 2^63-1.

```
select 
cast(conv(hash_col, 16, 10) as bigint) as p0, 
conv(hash_col, 16, 10) as c0 
from mytable limit 10
```

[image]

I have also tried using unhex(..),

```
cast(unhex(hash_col) as bigint) as p0 from mytable limit 10
```

but got the following error

> No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToLong
> with (binary). Possible choices: *FUNC*(bigint) *FUNC*(boolean)
> *FUNC*(decimal(38,18)) *FUNC*(double) *FUNC*(float) *FUNC*(int) *FUNC*(smallint) *FUNC*(string) *FUNC*(timestamp) *FUNC*(tinyint) *FUNC*(void)

If I don't do the `cast(.. as bigint)` part, I get some undisplayable binary value for p0. It seems `unhex` is not exactly the inverse of `hex` in hive.

Answer (score 0):

Your values are out of range for BigInt

Ref : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types

Max range for BigInt is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Use decimal(20,0) instead.

```
select cast(conv('85A58F8B014692CA',16,10) as decimal(20,0))
```